# Suitable prediction model for data with longitudinal and time invariant predictors

Tags: regression, logistic, panel-data, methodology, time-varying-covariate

I have a data set that obtained from a study that conducted at multiple time points(waves).Basically there are 4 waves. I used the data from first 3 waves to obtain the predictors and the response (dependent) variable is from wave 4. My goal is to develop a prediction model to predict response in wave 4 from the predictors in wave 1-3.

Predictors can be longitudinal(time varying) or can be time invariant (such predictor can be gender). Longitudinal predictors can be from all 3 waves or it can be from 2 waves out of 3.

My response variable is a binary variable.
For further clarification, this is how my data looks like.

```
ID   X1T1  X1T2 X1T3 X2T1 X2T2 X3 Y
 1     .     .    .     .   .    . .
 2     .     .    .     .   .    . . 
 .     .     .    .     .   .    . .
 .     .     .    .     .   .    . .
 .     .     .    .     .   .    . .
 N     .     .    .     .   .    . .
```

**I would want to know, what type of techniques can be applied to analysis this type of data**. I know it is not suitable to use standard logistic regression model  due to presence of time varying predictors.

I went through this paper also :https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22246815 .
But it contains how to analysis this type of data, when response also time varying.

Any suggestion would be great.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean repeated measures mancova? You can also use Multilevel modelling.